# How to run execute shell command in jenkins in different terminals

Tags: jenkins, protractor, package.json

I am running my protractor test through jenkins and my package.json looks like this:

```
{"name": "ProtractorTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "conf.js",
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "npm install && node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e-start": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "test": "protractor protractor.conf.js"
  }
```

I am trying to run script using jenkins execute shell build step like below
[Jenkins screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcR5v.png)

but this tries to run setup,e2e-start,test one after other.  Since "e2e-start" starts selenium server,so I see in console "INFO - Selenium Server is up and running...." and then npm run test is never run . I think it's because "npm run test" should be run in different terminal because when we run manually, we start server in one terminal and run test in different terminal. So, how can I achieve this using jenkins.

Comment: what is the problem doing from jenkins execute shell?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the bellow mentioned option in the config file then protractor will take care of starting and stopping of server itself, then you wont need to start and stop wendriver manager

```
    directConnect: true
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
```

Also you can mention selenium server jar too.

```
    seleniumServerJar: '../utils/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar',
    seleniumPort: 4444,
```

Another approach would be to use jenkins selenium pluggin

Comment: I cannot use directConnect : true, because this is only for chrome and firefox. My problem is to start the server and then start the test in jenkins. If in jenkin's execute shell section, I start server and then start test, then tests are never run because this has to be done in different terminals. Please see the jenkins screenshot I attached in my first post.

Comment: which browser you are using for test?

Comment: phantomjs or safari

Comment: please see the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

For phantomjs its easy.

1. Download the selenium server jar and save it in a folder.
2. in protractor conf.js file comment out directConnect and seleniumAddress.
3. Include them in your config.

   ```
   seleniumServerJar: 'location of the jar',
   seleniumPort: 4444,
   ```

These setting will start the selenium server before tests starts and shut it down gracefully when test finishes. you wont need to bother about starting selenium server explicitly.
Note: use selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar if you are using java 7

Comment: The way I achieved this is, I used gruntfile.js and using protractor-runner plugin, I specified the seleniumserver jar location. Then the protractor-runner takes care of starting the server and then starting the tests.